# Search Single Dimensional JSON array in SQL Query (["1", "2", ...])

Tags: mysql, json

I'm using `mysqlnd 5.0.10` and I've been trying to figure to figure out how to do `Field_A = Field_B` (`Field_A` being a JSON ARRAY).

Field_A = `["436","431","437","443","434"]`
Field_B = `436`

I've tried things such as

- `Field_A LIKE Field_B` (which isn't accurate enough)
- `JSON_TYPE(Field_A) IN (Field_B)`

The version of `mysql` does not have `JSON_EXTRACT`, only other way I can see this working is by `regex`

Comment: What is the data type of Field_B, is it an int?

Comment: Field_B is a INT(11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but the join does return the row you gave as an example (Field_A is decalared as JSON, Field_B as INT(11), value of Field_A is ["436", "431", "437", "443", "434"], value of Field_B is 436)

```
 select * from A join B
 ON A.Field_A LIKE CONCAT('%"', B.Field_B, '"%')
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I just spent few hours re-indexing all data lol but aw well.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out a feasible way to do this in MySQL, so I decided to parse all of the JSON data and move it into a separate table with INDEXING, then use said table to search `Field_A` against `Field_B`.

If someone does know a feasible way to do this, without moving all the data into an indexed table. I'm still interested.

Comment: did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find out a way to do it, I had to move data out of the column and into its own SQL table

Comment: even with a more recent version ? i am finding it hard to grasp the concept of querying  and sorting json associative array that are in a single SQL table column

Comment: @BobbyAxe we’ve only just upgraded our version so I haven’t had a chance to experiment yet